# dynamic field names in SOLR data importer

Tags: solr

Is it possible to specify dynamic field names from the query in the SOLR DataImporter? I found a couple of references that talk about a javascript workaround, but they were from 2010 so I"m hoping it just works now.

I am trying to implement like below. But the fields are being indexed with blank where the externalIdentifier should be.

```
<entity name="price" query="select pl.currencyUnit, pl.externalIdentifier, pl.label, pp.amount * 100 as 'amount', pp.wasAmount * 100 as 'wasAmount' from product_price_lists pl 
    inner join product_prices pp
    on pl.id = pp.priceList_id
    where pp.product_id = 1
    and pp.markForDelete = 0
    and publishDate &lt; now()
    and archiveDate is null or archiveDate &gt; now();
    ">
    <field column="amount" name="${price.externalIdentifier}__price" />
    <field column="wasAmount" name="${price.externalIdentifier}__price" />
    <field column="currencyUnit" name="${price.externalIdentifier}__currency__s" />
</entity>
```

Comment: are you sure that, this ${price.externalIdentifier} is having the value or is it used correctly? Ty with static value like 1_price, 2_currency_s. Once indexed, you can see who is the culprit

Comment: it's strange, I put a script transformer to generate one of the field names. And all the others started working too. But if I take out the script transformer, the values are gone again. It doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Add the field name Like. This

```
<dynamicField name="${price.externalIdentifier}__price" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
or 
<dynamicField name="${price.externalIdentifier}__price" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```